# sudo login root

Tags: root, sudo

I am trying to get root access on a webserver using:

```
    sudo login root
```

but I get:

```
    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I also don't have permission to the sudoers file. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sudo su -

If you are in the sudoer file, which it seems like you are not.

> su -

If you know the root password

If you have neither of these, the admin obviously doesn't want you to have root access.